# How can I match the exact user name to the exact password belongs to same user in python?

Tags: python

I have a CSV file with column name:

- name
- User name
- Password
- Strikes

I made a sign up system and a login system, in the login system I'm trying to make sure that the user name with the password he has at the same line, will be accepted when logged in.

I tried to do it and I can't find the way. It letting the user in with any password in the Database, even with a password of a different(other) username.

```py
import re
import random
import string
import csv
import pandas as pd
from os.path import exists

NAME = 'name'
users_data = pd.read_csv("users.csv")


def check_password(password):
    if len(password) < 8:
        return False
    if not re.search("[a-z]", password):
        return False
    if not re.search("[A-Z]", password):
        return False
    if not re.search("[0-9]", password):
        return False
    return True


def check_user(username):
    if username in users_data['User name'].tolist():
        return False
    else:
        return True


def check_user_login(username):
    if username in users_data['User name'].tolist():
        return True
    else:
        return False


def get_user_input_data():
    name = input("What is your name?> ")
    while not name.isalpha():
        name = input("Names can contain letter only, try again:")

    print(f"\nHello {name} !\n")
    username = input("Please choose your username> ")
    while not check_user(username):
        username = input("User already exist, Please choose a different username> ")
    use_generator = input("Would you like to get a password from the password generator? (yes/no) ")
    while use_generator not in ["yes", "no"]:
        use_generator = input("You have to insert (yes/no) only ")

    if use_generator == "yes":
        password = "".join(random.choice(robot) for i in range(8))
        print("Please copy your password:", password)

    if use_generator == "no":
        password = input("Please enter a 8 digit password (use capital letters and numbers)> ")
        while not check_password(password):
            password = input("You have to use capital letters and numbers. Please try again> ")

    return name, username, password


def user_login(users_data):
  counter = 0
  while True:
    open('users.csv', "r")
    username = input("Please enter your username> ")

    while not check_user_login(username):
        username = input("Invalid username, please try again> ")

    password = input("Please enter you password> ")
    if username in users_data['User name'].tolist() == password in users_data['Password'].tolist():
        print("Welcome")

    else:
        print("Details are wrong! Please try again")
        counter += 1
        if counter == 3:
           print(f"You tried wrongly {counter} times. Goodbye.")
           exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    robot = string.digits + string.ascii_letters
    initial_code = "".join(random.choice(robot) for i in range(6))
    print(f"Welcome to the Verification page,\nthe initial verification code is: {initial_code}\n")

    counter = 0
    while True:
        user_input_initial_code = input("Repeat the initial verification code>> ")
        if user_input_initial_code == initial_code:
            print("\nWelcome!\n")

            returning_user = input("Got an account? (yes/no)> ")
            while returning_user not in ["yes", "no"]:
                returning_user = input("Invalid answer, options are: (yes/no)")

            if returning_user == 'yes':
                user_login(users_data)
            else:
                get_user_input_data()

            break
        else:  # user_input_initial_code != initial_code:
            print("Wrong input code!")
            counter += 1

        if counter == 3:
            print(f"You tried wrongly {counter} times. Goodbye.")
            exit()

    while True:
        file_exists = exists("users.csv")
        if file_exists:
            users_data = pd.read_csv("users.csv")
        else:
            users_data = pd.DataFrame({NAME: [], 'User name': [], 'Password': [], 'Strikes': []})

        input_name, input_username, input_password = get_user_input_data()

        users_data = pd.concat([users_data, pd.DataFrame({NAME: input_name, 'User name': input_username,
                                                          'Password': input_password, 'Strikes': [0]})])
        users_data.to_csv('users.csv', index=False)

        exit()
```

Comment: That does not belong in pandas at all.  Just make it a dictionary where the key is the username, and the value is a dictionary with the password and strikes value.  Now, you can look it up easily.

Comment: Oh thank you! so all what i need to do is to change my data frame into a dictionary structure?

Comment: On a side note, this is a reasonable learning exercise, but please do not actually use this for a publicly available system. You should use libraries that manage passwords and users that others wrote rather than your own to avoid all of the security pitfalls.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a pandas problem in any way.  This shows how to read the data in to a dictionary and check the dictionary.  It's not clear from your code how you intend to add new usernames, but that's just a matter of adding another record to the `data` structure.

```
import csv

def importdata(fn):
    data = {}
    if exists(fn):
        for row in csv.DictReader(fn):
            data[row['User name']] = row
    return data

def exportdata(fn, data):
    f = csv.writer(fn)
    f.writerow("User name", "Password", "Strikes")
    for k,v in data:
        f.writerow( [k, v['Password'], v['Strikes']] )


def user_login(users_data):
    for counter in range(3):
        username = input("Please enter your username> ")

        if not username in users_data:
            print("Invalid username, please try again> ")
            continue

        password = input("Please enter you password> ")
        if users_data[username]['Password'] == password:
            print("Welcome")
            return True

        print("Details are wrong! Please try again")

    print(f"You tried wrongly 3 times. Goodbye.")
    exit()


data = importdata( 'users.csv' )
user_login(data)
```

Comment: I updated my code in my question so you could see all what i did. are you sure i did not need to use pandas? your example made me a bit confused... I don't understand some of your structure... I'm still a beginner (started this about 2 months ago)

Comment: @user21552442 I recommend that you learn about dictionaries. `pandas` is an extra later of complexity that is not necessary to solve the task.

Comment: Of course you do not need pandas.  ALL you are using pandas for is a cheap way to read a CSV file, but the data structure it produces is not suitable for your needs.  So, use a  more flexible way to read the CSV, and you can store stuff in a way you can use.